# objective-c block vs selector. which one is better?

Tags: objective-c, selector, objective-c-blocks

In objective-c when you are implementing a method that is going to perform a repetitive operations, for example, you need to choice in between the several options that the language brings you:

```
@interface FancyMutableCollection : NSObject { }
-(void)sortUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator;
// or ...
-(void)sortUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr;
@end
```

**I was wondering which one is *better*?**

Objective-c provides many options: selectors, blocks, pointers to functions, instances of a class that conforms a protocol, etc.

Some times the choice is clear, because only one method suits your needs, but what about the rest? I don't expect this to be just a matter of fashion.

**Are there any rules to know when to use selectors and when to use blocks?**

Comment: I *think* that blocks are an older language feature. This would lead me to assume that the @ directives are generally preferred. But I'm not a veteran by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: Can you expand a little on what you expect for the meaning of *better* (faster, easier to code, easier to read, less lines of code, etc)?

Comment: @AurumAquila: As far as I know, blocks were just recently introduced

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña blocks were indeed only introduced in ios 4.0

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wasn't 100% sure. Blocks look really clunky though, the only time I ever use them is when an Apple API requires them (UIView animation etc.).

**EDIT:** I wasn't 100% wrong, blocks were created for Leopard and Grand Central. They only just got added to iOS 4 though. They are still younger than the Obj-C 2.0 spec stuff though :(

Comment: @AurumAquila clunky based on looks is probably the same conclusion you came to when you first saw objective-c. In practice though they are a lot like Javascript callbacks/closures or Ruby blocks, which can be very useful and idiomatic. They have some nice advantages too. Of course, they are no silver bullet.

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña, you're right about me being a surface looks person. I tried iPhone programming back when the SDK first came out and I gave up. I got into it again a year ago and it's been a blast.

Comment: @AurumAquila: `@selector()` has been in the language since at least the '90s (I don't have any docs from the '80s at hand to confirm whether it existed back then, but it wouldn't surprise me).

Comment: @chown you are right, _better_ is not very specific; I was thinking in both faster and easier to mantain. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main difference I can think of is that with blocks, they act like closures so they capture all of the variables in the scope around them. This is good for when you already have the variables there and don't want to create an instance variable just to hold that variable temporarily so that the action selector can access it when it is run.

With relation to collections, blocks have the added ability to be run concurrently if there are multiple cores in the system. Currently in the iPhone there isn't, but the iPad 2 does have it and it is probable that future iPhone models will have multiple cores. Using blocks, in this case, would allow your app to scale automatically in the future.

In some cases, blocks are just easier to read as well because the callback code is right next to the code that's calling it back. This is not always the case of course, but when sometimes it does simply make the code easier to read.

Sorry to refer you to the documentation, but for a more comprehensive overview of the pros/cons of blocks, take a look at [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH1-SW1).

As Apple puts it:

> Blocks represent typically small, self-contained pieces of code. As such, they’re particularly useful as a means of encapsulating units of work that may be executed concurrently, or over items in a collection, or as a callback when another operation has finished.
>
> Blocks are a useful alternative to traditional callback functions for two main reasons:
>
> They allow you to write code at the point of invocation that is executed later in the context of the method implementation.
>   Blocks are thus often parameters of framework methods.
>
> They allow access to local variables.
>   Rather than using callbacks requiring a data structure that embodies all the contextual information you need to perform an operation, you simply access local variables directly.

On [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH3-SW1)

Comment: Using selectors is not known as "target-action pattern".   That is limited to the relationship between UI elements and whatever object (target) and method (action) should handle the user's activating the UI element (think button press).

Answer (score 4):

The one that's better is whichever one works better in the situation at hand. If your objects all implement a comparison selector that supports the ordering you want, use that. If not, a block will probably be easier.

Comment: the selector approach is also good if you're going to be using this sorting code in >1 place. otherwise the block is an easy way to do it and keep it all inline.

Comment: But you can define a global block and use it like you would do with a selector or a function pointer. So, apparently, selectors and blocks can work the same in most circumstances.