# When to use Blocks?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

When we should use cocoa blocks in our program?

I know that a block has access to ivars and private properties and can be called/used like a variable, and is faster than methods. I also seen apple uses sorting of arrays using blocks. But I have worry about under what requirement we should use blocks?

Please waiting for answer.

Comment: I've always assumed they were for when something requires a method to run but that method is only going to be used by that something, so instead of writing out a separate method, you just do it inline so its more readable in a sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [objective-c block vs selector. which one is better?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562256/objective-c-block-vs-selector-which-one-is-better) and [this one too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176961/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-blocks)

Comment: Quick-shot: Here's a good article about that topic: ["Blocks or Delegation?"](http://thejoeconwayblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/blocks-or-delegation/)